# Linking existing folder to external folder in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to link existing folder in a project to external folder in eclipse.

Please suggest me the procedure or alternatives if any.

Comment: Please see the link below 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492293/eclipse-and-external-src-and-web-content-folder-linking-or-mapping

Answer (score 1):

You can drag your external folder from the file system and drop it into the Eclipse project. It will prompt you if you want to copy or link the resource.